# Unable to plot kernel density in MASS package - In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Tags: r, plot, kernel-density

When trying to plot my data I get these error messages:

```
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

This reproducible code works:

```
# some dummy data
library(mvtnorm)
dat <- rmvnorm(10000, mean=c(x=4,y=4), sigma=matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1), ncol=2))
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

# 2d density plot
library(MASS)
kdexy <- kde2d(dat$x,dat$y, n=50)
image(kdexy, col=grey(seq(1,0.2,length=10)))
```

But using my real data doesn't:

```
kdexy <- kde2d(temp$V1, temp$V2, n=50)
image(kdexy, col=grey(seq(1,0.2,length=10)))
```

Yet the structure of the two data sets is the same (the dummy data [dat] and the real data [temp]):

```
> str(dat$x)
 num [1:80000] 0.669 0.609 -0.633 0.565 0.559 ...
> str(temp$V1)
 num [1:823180] 0 0 0 0 0.0146 ...
> summary(dat$x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-4.2270 -0.1902  0.4841  0.4900  1.1600  5.3570 
> summary(temp$V1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0289  0.0000  0.9844 
> range(dat$x)
[1] -4.227400  5.357184
> range(temp$V1)
[1] -1.000000  0.984375
> str(temp$V2)
 num [1:823180] 1 1 15.5 15.5 18.5 ...
> summary(temp$V2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    1.00   18.45   23.55   35.96  116.10 
> range(temp$V2)
[1]   1.0000 116.0829
```

They are both stored in dataframes and the only difference I'm aware of is the length, and that `temp$V1` is bounded at `-1` and `1`.

The output of `kdexy <- kde2d()` differs between the two datasets. In the example data, the `Z` sections is populated with very small numbers; in the real dataset, every point is filled with 'NaN'.

Comment: Well your real data uses vectors from `t_plotdata` and `t_data` objects whilst your summary is for a vector from the `clean_data` object. Are these objects the same? Perhaps you have an NA in either your `t_data` object? What do you get with `range(t_data$change)`?

Comment: I've corrected the outputs - to emulate the working dummy data even more, I've stored two variables in a dataframe (`temp`), just like the dummy data (`dat`). Still doesn't work! I've added the outputs from `range()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data are heavily concentrated around 0 (`total n=850,000`, `n==0 ~ 650,000`). Using a subset of data, where `x<0` (`n=150,000`), the plots work.